How to Create a Horizontally Scrollable Table with Dynamic Width Adjustment?
I'm facing a challenge with creating a horizontally scrollable table that dynamically adjusts its width based on the content. Here's the scenario:
I have a table with a lot of columns, and I want it to behave in the following manner on a column to column basis:

If no Max Width is Defined (on th/td): If no maximum width is set, the column should expand horizontally to fit the content.

If a Max Width is Defined (on th/td): If a maximum width is set, the column should wrap the content to fit within that width.

Optimal Space Usage: The column should only take up the minimum space needed to fit the content, and not more.


I plan to create breakpoints to adjust the table's behavior for different screen sizes.
I've tried various approaches, including setting overflow: auto; or overflow: scroll; on the table container, but the table still tries to shrink as much as possible by wrapping words wherever it can. Setting a min-width would work, but it would make the width static, which is not ideal as I want it to be dynamic based on the content.white-space: nowrap on the table will prevent the text from wrapping even if max width is set.
I support multiple languages, and the content length can vary significantly between languages like Japanese and Russian. I don't want to waste space, as it would make the table look unappealing.
Here's a JSFiddle example demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/e6rdcL75/15/


.container {
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 200px; /* this does not work */
}
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Weatherometer</th>
            <th>Rhabdophobia</th>
            <th>Batrachophagous</th>
            <th>Logizomechanophobia</th>
            <th>Zalambdodont</th>
            <th>Honorificabilitudinitatibus</th>
            <th>Kakorrhaphiophobia</th>
            <th>Maschalephidrosis</th>
            <th>Ubiquitarianism</th>
            <th>Micropalaeontology</th>
            <th>Ecclesiasticus</th>
            <th>Libanophorous</th>
            <th>Graminivorous</th>
            <th>Paleophytologist</th>
            <th>Zalambdodont</th>
            <th>Metathesiophobia</th>
            <th>Fissigemmation</th>
            <th>Whippersnappers</th>
            <th>Ablutophobia</th>
            <th>Otorhinolaryngology</th>
            <th>Palaeoanthropology</th>
            <th>Umbraculiform</th>
            <th>Quadragesimarian</th>
            <th>Immunopathology</th>
            <th>Ostraconophobia</th>
            <th>Roentgenometrics</th>
            <th>Ballistocardiograph</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Instrument for measuring weather-resisting properties of paint</td>
            <td>Fear of being severely punished or beaten by a rod, or of being severely criticized</td>
            <td>A person who eats frogs</td>
            <td>Fear of computers</td>
            <td>Having molar teeth with V-shaped ridges</td>
            <td>One bearing honorableness</td>
            <td>Fear of failure</td>
            <td>Excessive sweating of the armpits</td>
            <td>Belief in the omnipresence of God</td>
            <td>Study of microscopic fossils</td>
            <td>An Apocryphal book</td>
            <td>Producing incense</td>
            <td>Feeding on grass or cereals</td>
            <td>One versed in the recovery and identification of plant fossils from geological contexts</td>
            <td>Having molar teeth with V-shaped ridges</td>
            <td>Fear of changes</td>
            <td>A process of reproduction that intercedes fission and gemmation</td>
            <td>People considered insignificant and pretentious</td>
            <td>Fear of washing or having a bath</td>
            <td>It is a study of ear, nose, and throat</td>
            <td>The study of early humans</td>
            <td>Umbrella-shaped</td>
            <td>One who observes Lent</td>
            <td>Study of immunity to disease</td>
            <td>Fear of shellfish</td>
            <td>A chiropractic technique involving the study of X-rays by biomechanical analysis and measurement</td>
            <td>An instrument which is used to detect body movements caused by heartbeats</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
   




Your post includes a list of three behaviours, but these behaviours are mutually exclusive – it is impossible to implement them all at the same time. Please edit your post to make clear when each of these behaviours should be used. For example, do you want behaviour 1 on wide screens and behaviour 3 on narrow screens? Or do you want some of your tables to have behaviour 1 and others to have behaviour 2 or 3?

@BrettDonald I think 1 and 3 you mean? I corrected it. Maybe my wording is bad.
Yes I want all 3 at the same time. So by default the columns should take all the horizontal space. Because the table is in a scrollable container the space is basically endless. So If I had a 200 word text it's td should extend to the right to fit the whole text.
Additionally, I want to limit the maximum width on a column level. But I don't want a column to have a minimum width defined. The minimum width should be the size that the content requires to display correctly.

So on some columns you will to set a max-width, and on other columns you will not set a max-width? Please edit your post to clarify. I am happy to help you but I will not do so until your post clearly describes your requirements, and I fully understand them.

Hello @BrettDonald,
I made some changes to the 3 requirements. I changed "table" to "column" because it's about the column width behavior and not the general table width behavior.
I also added "if max width" is defined to indicate that there are two cases, and they can differentiate on a column to column basis. I said max-width because I think this describes the behavior I want best, even if that CSS property might not work here.

So, to sum it up. Columns should just expand to the "right side" to fit the content inside, but not take more space than needed. (1. and 3.)
And if a max width is set on a column it should wrap the content to fit that width.
@BrettDonald so to clearly answer your question, yes I want the columns to expand by default and on some I want to define a maximum width. I hope this is now more clear in the post.
